# Shortcut to Apply a Formula to an Entire Column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I select a cell containing a formula, I know I can drag the little box in the right-hand corner downwards to apply the formula to more cells of the column. Unfortunately, I need to do this for 300,000 rows!

Is there a shortcut, similar to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, that will apply a formula to the entire column, or to a selected part of the column?

Answer (score 678, accepted):

Try double-clicking on the bottom right hand corner of the cell (ie on the box that you would otherwise drag).

Comment: Works perfectly in LibreOffice Calc as well, +1.

Comment: @soo Is there a way we can programmatically do it, so that once new row entries are defined, the formula for sum automatically applies to the cell in the new row.

Comment: Nothing happened when I did this in Office for Mac; I'm sure there's a discrepancy between the two versions.

Comment: You glorious individual. Worked great on Office for Mac. MacOS 10.8.4 with Excel 2008 Version 12.1.1

Comment: Did not work for me.  Tried Phil's answer instead with success.   Using Excel 2007.

Comment: also works for libreoffice.

Comment: also does not work on excel 2010

Comment: If this doesn't work, you may try clearing the entire column first; obviously not your cell with formula though.

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed that I've never heard of this tip before... I wonder how long Excel has had this little capability?

Comment: This did not work in Excel 2013 with the formula already applied to one cell.  Ctrl+D worked in RobinCTS post.

Comment: works even in WPS office 10.1 (linux version)

Comment: How is double-clicking a shortcut?

Comment: This will not work if the formula column is not right against the data column so make sure there is no blank column in between.

Comment: Works for me in Excel 2010. @EvilWashingMachine

Comment: nicely hidden, microsoft excel crashes when attempted this with a match function or vlookup on a dataset spanning million rows, totally as expected from office 365 in 2019

Comment: In Mac version 16.25 it didn't work by default. 
But when I add filtering (Home -> Sort & Filter), so those arrows directed to down was added to every column I was able to double-click and it nicely copy my formula to all cells in column.

Answer (score 231):

If the formula already exists in a cell you can fill it down as follows:

- Select the cell containing the formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> to select the rest of the column (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> to select up to the last row where there is data)
- Fill down by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> to return up

On Mac, use <kbd>CMD</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

An alternative if the formula is in the first cell of a column:

- Select the entire column by clicking the column header or selecting any cell in the column and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>
- Fill down by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: Whether it slow or not, but no regret to try this one, but it will really slow just for making the formula on to the bottom. Total rows on Libre Office is 1,048,576 rows when I tried this method, it took me around 15 minutes just to fill a row number formula. :D

Comment: ctrl + shift + down does not work on mac

Comment: Mac users: `cmd + shift + down`, then `ctrl + d`

Comment: For only (not empty) column use: CTRL+SHIFT+END

Comment: Works perfectly on Google Sheets too.

Comment: FYI, if you know how many rows you're working with, it's more efficient to  Ctrl+G select a cell in the last row, then do Ctrl+Shift+UP, so that you don't apply the formula to a bunch of empty cells.

Comment: Ctrl+space and  ctrl+down is the answer I was looking for, thanks @robinCTS

Comment: When applying the same formula in the whole row, `fill right (CTRL + R)` and not down.

Answer (score 95):

Select a range of cells (the entire column in this case), type in your formula, and hold down Ctrl while you press Enter. This places the formula in all selected cells.

Comment: Wow. Yes you are right. I didn't know what you meant by "introducing a `Shift`" but you are absolutely correct. I was describing a `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` behavior, not a `Ctrl+Enter` behavior!